# How do you import a large number of repositories to bitbucket easily?

Tags: bitbucket

I have around 100 repositories in github and I have to import all of them to bitbucket. What is the easiest automated way of doing it ?

Comment: Ok I found how to do it myself. Use the following command:

    curl --request POST --user username:password https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/ --data name=myrepo --data scm=git

Reference: http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Repositories

Comment: Great that you solved this yourself! Please post the answer below as a real answer. You can accept the answer after two days.

Comment: With v1 API deprecated, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/41647/script-to-import-repositories-to-bitbucket#comment-454978 might be the way to go

Answer (score 2):

Answer added from comment:

Use the following command:

```
curl --request POST --user username:password https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories --data name=myrepo --data scm=git
```